# Não retorna data no input

Tags: php, html

Pretendo mostrar sempre a terça anterior no input e para isso faço-o desta forma:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'previous tuesday' );
$terca = date($dia->format('d-m-Y'));
```

Depois pretendo mostrar a variável `$terca` no `value` de num `input` `type` `date`, mas não mostra, só se for `datetime`:

```
<td style="float:center"> <input type="date" name= "data"  value="<?php echo $terca?>"></td>
```

Sempre que executo a página recebo este aviso:

> The specified value "19-02-2019" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: Você viu qual é o "required format" na mensagem de erro?

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss O "required format" é o `datetime` mas eu pretendo que o input seja tipo `date` para caso queira mudar a data aparecer o calendário. Já tentei converter a variável para `date` mas continuo sem conseguir visualizar a data a não ser que utilize o `datetime`

Comment: Não confunda tipo com formato. Você tentou inserir um valor no formato d-m-Y em um campo que exige o formato yyyy-MM-dd. É exatamente isso que diz a mensagem de erro.

Comment: @Anderson Carlos Woss Estou a tentar desta forma `date('yyyy-MM-dd', strtotime($terca));` mas continuo com o mesmo problema

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você entende exatamente o que está fazendo ou está tentando códigos avulsos? Com o `$dia->format` você formata seu objeto `DateTime` para *string*; depois com a função `strtotime` você cria novamente um objeto data a partir da sua *string* e depois formata de novo para uma nova *string*. Mesmo sendo iniciante, evite ficar fazendo essas tentativas avulsas. Não funcionou? Pare e reveja linha a linha o que você fez e veja se faz algum sentido. Nesse caso não fez.

O campo [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/data) espera um valor no formato yyyy-MM-dd, isto é, ano com 4 dígitos, mês com 2 dígitos (zero à esquerda) e dia com 2 dígitos (zero à esquerda). Para gerar isso com PHP basta fazer:

```
$dia->format('Y-m-d');
```

Para mais detalhes do que faz cada letra [leia a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters).

Por exemplo:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'previous tuesday' );
$terca = $dia->format('Y-m-d');

echo sprintf('<input type="date" value="%s">', $terca);
```

O que gera:

```html
<input type="date" value="2019-02-19">
```