# Obter a data da primeira terça feira de cada mês

Tags: php

Para retorna a terça feira anterior faço desta forma:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'previous tuesday' );
$terca = $dia->format('Y-m-d');
```

Agora pretendia retornar a primeira terça feira de cada mês

Comment: Por qual motivo continua usando `date($dia->format('Y-m-d'))`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para você pegar a ***próxima terça que inicia em cada mês*** utilize `this tuesday`, exemplo:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'this tuesday' );
echo $terca = $dia->format('Y-m-d');
```

---

E para pegar a ***primeira terça-feira do mês corrente*** faça:

```
$dia = new DateTime();
$dia->modify( 'first tuesday of F Y' );
echo $terca = $dia->format('Y-m-d');
```

Acredito que a opção esperada seja a segunda.

<sup>***Referencia:*** [Formatos relativos - DateTime/date_create()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.formats.relative.php)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

Como eu comentei em [Não retorna data no input](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/364935/5878) não faz sentido algum fazer:

```
$terca = date($dia->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Você cria um objeto `DateTime`, formata em uma *string* para utilizar de novo em `date`? Reforço o que eu disse de não escrever código aleatório sem entender o que está fazendo. Se não entende, pare e busque entender. Vai usar uma função? Leia a documentação, conheça os parâmetros, saiba qual será o retorno e, principalmente, saiba o que ela faz, de fato. Só assim saberá se é realmente o que precisa naquele momento.

Você pode retornar a primeira terça-feira de um mês com:

```
function get_first_tuesday($year, $month) {
    return new DateTime("first tuesday of {$year}-{$month}");
}

echo get_first_tuesday('2019', '02')->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;  // 2019-02-05
```

E buscar todas as primeiras terça-feiras de cada mês de um ano com:

```
function get_first_tuesdays_of_year($year) {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
        yield get_first_tuesday($year, $i);
    }
}

$tuesdays = get_first_tuesdays_of_year(2019);

foreach ($tuesdays as $tuesday) {
    echo $tuesday->format('Y-m-d'), PHP_EOL;
}
```

O resultado seria:

```
2019-01-01
2019-02-05
2019-03-05
2019-04-02
2019-05-07
2019-06-04
2019-07-02
2019-08-06
2019-09-03
2019-10-01
2019-11-05
2019-12-03
```

Na verdade, você nem precisa da classe `DateTime` aqui. Poderia fazer:

```
function get_first_tuesday($year, $month, $format = 'Y-m-d') {
    return date($format, strtotime("first tuesday of {$year}-{$month}"));
}
```

Que também funcionaria.

Comment: tem toda a razão, foi falta de atenção ao comentário que colocou na outra pergunta, realmente não faz sentido